# Jasmine spyOn doesn't go to .then function with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Here is my controller

```
function test(){
    console.log('trace1'); // this gets print on console
    myService.useService('someStuff')
      .then(function(data){
          console.log('trace2'); // this doesn't get print
      })
      .catch(function(error){
          console.log('trace3'); // this doesn't get print    
      });
}
```

Here is my test suite

```
describe('test controller promise', function () {

    beforeEach(inject(function(
        $controller,
        $q,
        _$rootScope_,
        $location,
        $anchorScroll,
        _myService_,
        $window
    ) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        myService = _myService_;

        var testDeferred = $q.defer();
        testDeferred.reject('some_error_message');

        spyOn(myService, 'useService').and.callFake(function(){
            console.log('trace 5');  // this gets called
            return testDeferred.promise
        });

        myController = $controller('myController', {
            $rootScope: $rootScope,
            myService: myService,
            $location: $location,
            $anchorScroll: $anchorScroll,
            $window
        });

        $rootScope.$apply();
    }));

    it('test promise', function () {
        myController.test();

        // we see trace1 and trace5 gets called but not trace2 and trace3
});
```

I want either `.then` or `.catch` to be called after the mock service is called (ideally I should be seeing `trace3` to get printed since I used `reject`), but we see that it doesn't get called since `trace2` and `trace3` doesn't get printed, but what is curious is that the Fake function does get called since `trace5` gets printed

I've tried `callFake` , `returnValue` and using both `reject` and `resolve` , all of them does not result in `.then` or `.catch` to be called. What am I missing?